# Converting String value to Float - using textbox

Tags: c#, string, textbox, floating-point, type-conversion

I'm serializing object to json using Newtonsoft.
One of the fields that are supposed to be filled is a field containing a numeric value - a float exactly. When I was creating a car object in my project, I used float in my constructor. Like this:

```
 public class brakes
    {
        public float park_brake { get; set; }
        public float work_brake { get; set; }
        public float discrepancy { get; set; }
    }
```

User will fill the textBox which is a string but it is supposed to be a float. Is there a way to convert it? Found something like this but it's not working

```
Car.tires.front_value_mm = (float)Convert.ToDouble(textBox.Text);
```

Comment: Why is it not working? What is the error message? What is the decimal delimiter, comma or point?

Comment: Delimiter is comma and I get System.FormatException: invalid input string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using

```
float f1 = float.Parse(textBox.Text);
```

**Edit** - The solution that worked...

```
float f1 = (float)double.Parse(textBox.Text)
```

Comment: System.FormatException: invalid input string

Comment: In my case it supposed to look like this Car.tires.front_value_mm = float.Parse(textBox.Text); and there is exception in this case

Comment: using (float)double.Parse(textBox.Text) helps?

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
    public class brakes
    {
        private float _park_brake { get; set; }
        private float _work_brake { get; set; }
        private float _discrepancy { get; set; }
        public string park_brake
        {
            get { return _park_brake.ToString(); }
            set { _park_brake = float.Parse(value); }
        }
        public string work_brake
        {
            get { return _work_brake.ToString(); }
            set { _work_brake = float.Parse(value); }
        }
        public string discrepancy
        {
            get { return _discrepancy.ToString(); }
            set { _discrepancy = float.Parse(value); }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `float.Parse()` or the `float.TryParse()` method.

`float.Parse()` is given a `string` and it returns the `float` value that the `string` contains.

`float.TryParse()` is given a `string` and the `float` variable to set as an `out` parameter and it returns a `bool`. It is much safer than `float.Parse()` since it returns `true`, when the parsing was successful. This allows you to check if the `string` is a valid `float`.

Unfortunately, `float-strings` can be written with a `.` or with a `,` depending on the culture you are in. Make sure the culture you give the Parse-Method matches the culture you are using in your application. You can get it from `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`. Be sure to set the correct Culture for the input, otherwise it will fail.

Here is some example code:

```
float value;
if(!float.TryParse(textBox.Text, out value,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Wrong input!");
}
```

Sources: [`float.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2thct5cb(v=vs.110).aspx) [`float.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xh24xh4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I cannot use 

float value and later on pt into TryParse,

In my case, it supposed to look like this :

    if (!float.TryParse(textBox.Text, out Auto1.tires.front_value_mm,
                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong input!");
            }

but it's not working, cause
Can not pass property or indexer as parameter "out" or "ref"

Comment: You may want to use a float variable that holds the value just for parsing and then assign it to the property.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that using float.Parse() makes any difference. Try this:

```
Car.tires.front_value_mm = (float)Convert.ToDouble(textBox.Text, new NumberFormatInfo() {  NumberDecimalSeparator = "," });
```